# How to _not_ strip HTML comments from a HTML template in gin gonic

Tags: html, go, go-gin

I'm using Gin Gonic with a HTML template file.

My template file contains (multi line) HTML comments of the kind `<!-- my comment goes here-->`.
I want that the HTML content is preserved in the output which is returned by

```golang
c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "static/templates/mytemplate.html", gin.H{
    "name": "World",
})
```

where `c` is a `*gin.Context`.

**Question**: How to configure the template engine or c.HTML to *not* strip the HTML comments from the template?

#### More Detailed

`/static/templates/mytemplate.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<body>
<!--
these lines are missing in the output
-->
Hello World
</body>
</html>
```

My Handler:

```golang
func NewRouter() *gin.Engine {
    router := gin.Default()
    // ... load templates from file system ...
    router.GET("/foo", fooHandler)
    return router
}
func fooHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "static/templates/mytemplate.html", gin.H{
        "name": "World",
    })
}
```

**Edit**
I tried to add the comments as constants:

```html
{{"<!-- my comment goes here -->"}}
```

But then the tags are escaped as

```html
&lt;!-- foo --&gt;
```

Comment: HTML comments are usually not stripped from the output. How did you verify they are stripped?

Comment: I started the server and checked the HTML.

Comment: Checked the HTML with what? curl? Browser? Did you look at the page source, or used developer tools of some sort? I can see the HTML comments coming from my server.

Answer (score 1):

I *guess* the reason why the HTML comment is stripped is because I read the HTML template as string (instead of as file directly). Still cannot nail it down exactly.
Anyway, the workaround that did the job for me, was to use a place holder in the template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<body>
{{ .myComment }}
Hello World
</body>
</html>
```

And pass the HTML comment itself as parameter:

```golang
const myHtmlComment string = `
<!--
these lines are (not) missing (anymore) in the output
-->
`
func fooHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "static/templates/mytemplate.html", gin.H{
        "name": "World",
        "myComment": template.HTML(myHtmlComment),
    })
}
```

with `import "html/template"`